# Как перечислить выполненные команды одной строкой?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Нужно чтобы при выполнении аргументов, к примеру **/h** и **/e** появился примерно такой ответ:

`Команда /h /e выполнена`

или

`Выполнено: /h /e`

Код в файле Program.cs

```
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "/h":
                    form.Check1();
                    Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /h выполнена");
                    break;

                case "/s":
                    form.Check2();
                    Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /s выполнена");
                    break;

                case "/e":
                    form.Check3();
                    Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /e выполнена");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что выполнив два аргумента, получаем две строки, а нужно, чтобы аргументы были перечислены в одной строке.

Comment: Так перечислите их.

Comment: Я новичок в C# поэтому прошу у знатоков :)

Comment: Какая длинная эпопея у вас с этими командами...

Answer (score 2):

1. Перед циклом объявляем список, в который будем добавлять обработанные параметры:

   `var processedArgs=new List<string>();`
2. В каждом `case` вместо вывода параметра на экран добавляем обработанный параметр в список:

   `processedArgs.Add(arg);`
3. По завершении цикла склеиваем и выводим:

   `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Команда {0} выполнена", String.Join(" ", processedArgs)));`

Comment: На третьем этапе, для **cmds** пишет: Не удается преобразовать из `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` в `string[]`

Comment: ошибся processedArgs а не cmds

Comment: странно, у меня в VS2015 отработало нормально. Ну, тогда само собой делаем `processedArgs.ToArray()`. Хотя перегрузка, принимающая IEnumerable у String.Join есть: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Перед циклом объяви какую-нибудь строковую переменную, а внутри каждого case приплюсовывай к ней саму себя+ идентификатор команды.

Если всего 3 команды, то вполне хватит типа `string`.

Если будет много команда, то лучше воспользоваться `StringBuilder`, который создает меньше работы для сборщика мусора.